# get the selected index value of <select> tag in php

Tags: php

I was trying  to get the selected value from the `<select>` tag in PHP, but I get errors.

These is what I have done,

HTML

```
<select name="gender">
<option value="select">  Select </option>
<option value="male">    Male   </option>
<option value="female">  Female </option>
</select>
```

PHP script

```
$Gender  = $_POST["gender"];
```

but i get these error

```
Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\omnama\signup.php on line 7
```

php script

```
$Gender  = isset($_POST["gender"]); ' it returns a empty string ? why ?
```

HTML

```
<form name="signup_form"  action="./signup.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()"   method="post">
<table> 
  <tr> <td> First Name    </td><td> <input type="text" name="fname" size=10/></td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Last Name     </td><td> <input type="text" name="lname" size=10/></td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Your Email    </td><td> <input type="text" name="email" size=10/></td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Re-type Email </td><td> <input type="text" name="remail"size=10/></td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Password      </td><td> <input type="password" name="paswod" size=10/> </td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Gender        </td><td> <select name="gender">
  <option>                Select </option>    
  <option value="male">   Male   </option>
  <option value="female"> Female </option></select></td></tr> 
  <tr> <td> <input type="submit" value="Sign up" id="signup"/> </td> </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

This is my php script

```
  <?php
  $con     = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  $fname   = $_POST["fname"];
  $lname   = $_POST["lname"];
  $email   =  $_POST["email"];
  $paswod  = $_POST["paswod"];
  $Gender  = $_POST["gender"];
  mysql_select_db("homepage");

  if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Email = '$email'",$con)))
  {
  echo "userid is already there";
  }
  else
  { 
  $sql= "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName,Email,Password,Gender)
  VALUES
  ('$fname','$lname','$email','$paswod','$Gender')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo "created";
  }
 ?>
```

Please help me with these. I have to get the selected index value in the PHP.

I have read this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/48477-how-to-get-the-select-value-from-the-drop-down-list/) to use `<select>` tag in PHP.

Comment: `$Gender  = isset($_POST["gender"]); ' it returns a null string ? why ?` --- this code **cannot** return `null`, by definition

Comment: null ! there i mean when i open and see mysql i see an empty string in the database!

Comment: Is your form a valid form? Mean, between the `<form></form>` tags and with a submit button

Comment: @niko: empty string is not the same thing as `null`. Use `var_dump($Gender);` and `var_dump($_POST);` to see what actually you have (without further *guesses*)

Comment: yes ofcourse i can store the first name last name email and everything in the database except these select tag

Comment: why do we use var_dump ? actually im kinda new to php i was writing small snippets to make myself understand

Comment: so the problem might be in your query? post it too, please. With var_dump() you see the content (with type) of the variable you pass it, so you can see if your $_POST or $Gender are what they should be

Comment: try this and see what is the output
$Gender  = isset($_POST["gender"])?$_POST["gender"]:"";

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is your form not being correct, maybe your select tags are in wrong position

Comment: Can you show your <form> also? That should clear it up right away, instead of us just guessing what it looks like.

Comment: i have updated! my html and php

Comment: try add `selected=selected` attribute for default value instead using an option named `select` so if default is Female, then `<option selected="selected" value="female">Female</option>`. So even user didn't select the gender, it would submitted as `female`

Comment: And [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) rides *again*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your form is valid. Only thing that comes to my mind is, after seeing your full html, is that you're passing your "default" value (which is not set!) instead of selecting something.
Try as suggested by @Vina in the comment, i.e. giving it a selected option, or writing a default value

```
<select name="gender">
<option value="default">Select </option>    
<option value="male">   Male   </option>
<option value="female"> Female </option>
</select>
```

OR

```
<select name="gender">
<option value="male" selected="selected">   Male   </option>
<option value="female"> Female </option>
</select>
```

When you get your $_POST vars, check for them being set; you can assign a default value, or just an empty string in case they're not there.

**Most important thing, AVOID SQL INJECTIONS:**

```
//....
$fname   = isset($_POST["fname"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']) : '';
$lname   = isset($_POST['lname']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']) : '';
$email   = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : '';
you might also want to validate e-mail:
if($mail = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
}
else
{
  //die ('invalid email address');
  // or whatever, a default value? $email = '';
}
$paswod  = isset($_POST["paswod"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['paswod']) : '';
$gender  = isset($_POST['gender']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']) : '';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Email = '".$email."')";
if(mysql_num_rows($query)> 0)
{
  echo 'userid is already there';
}
else
{
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, Gender)
         VALUES ('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."','".paswod."','".$gender."')";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
echo 'created';
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said..

```
$Gender  = isset($_POST["gender"]); ' it returns a empty string
```

because, you haven't mention method type either use POST or GET, by default it will use GET method. On the other side, you are trying to retrieve your value by using POST method, but in the form you haven't mentioned POST method. Which means miss-match method will result for empty.

Try this code..

```
<form name="signup_form"  action="./signup.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()"   method="post">
<table> 
  <tr> <td> First Name    </td><td> <input type="text" name="fname" size=10/></td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Last Name     </td><td> <input type="text" name="lname" size=10/></td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Your Email    </td><td> <input type="text" name="email" size=10/></td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Re-type Email </td><td> <input type="text" name="remail"size=10/></td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Password      </td><td> <input type="password" name="paswod" size=10/> </td></tr>
  <tr> <td> Gender        </td><td> <select name="gender">
  <option value="select">                Select </option>    
  <option value="male">   Male   </option>
  <option value="female"> Female </option></select></td></tr> 
  <tr> <td> <input type="submit" value="Sign up" id="signup"/> </td> </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

and on signup page

```
$Gender  = $_POST["gender"];
```

i'm sure.. now, you will get the value..

Comment: I have used method="post" in my html.sorry but you missed it,behind the scroll ! anyways thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
echo $gender;
```

it will echoes the selected value.