# Pulling data for WordPress Jetpack plugin contact form

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I have a small form on my website, which I created using Jetpack plugin (it has built-in contact form creator).

I want to pull options for select input from my custom-post-type "`artist`" (using the titles of the posts). Is there a way to do it?

```
[contact-field label='Artist' type='select' required='1' options='i want my titles go here separated by commas plus "other" option'/]
```

The code for the field looks like this. I believe I need to do some php+jquery stuff in this page template, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695599/get-the-selected-index-value-of-select-tag-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some creativity, yes, it's possible :)

We create another Shortcode to create a "virtual" JetPack shortcode.

I tested this using the default post post_type.

```
add_shortcode( 'my-jet-form', 'so_14003883_jet_form' );

function so_14003883_jet_form( $atts, $content ) 
{
    // Query our post type, change accordingly
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'    => 'post',
        'numberposts'  => -1,
        'post_status'  => 'publish'
    ) );

    // Build an array of post titles
    $titles = array();
    foreach( $posts as $post )
    {
        $titles[] = $post->post_title;
    }

    // Convert array into comma sepparated string
    $posts_select = implode( ',', $titles );

    // Make JetPack shortcode
    $return = do_shortcode( '[contact-form][contact-field label="Name" type="name" required="1"/][contact-field label="Artist" type="select" options="' . $posts_select . '"/][/contact-form]' );
    return $return;
}
```

**Usage**:

- adjust the desired post type
- adjust the `do_shortcode` part to suit your original shortcode
- put the shortcode `[my-jet-form]` wherever you want
- voilà