# Selecting Data from select tag

Tags: html

i have to  select data from select tag rather then selecting value as its selects value for default

```
<select name="time"  >
        <option selected="selected" >timings</option>
        <option value="155">9:00AM - 12:00PM</option>
        <option value="244">12:00AM - 15:00PM</option>
        </select>
```

I want to select 12:00AM - 15:00PM values and store it in my DB. How to do it any ideas.

Thanks in advance

Ameeth

Comment: Simple as `value="12:00AM - 15:00PM"`

Comment: your select box is dynamic or static?

Comment: value which u r using in option tag will POST/GET on other/same page from ur form..so watever values u want to store into ur DB, take those values as value in Option tag

Comment: Check : [get the selected index value of <select> tag in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695599/get-the-selected-index-value-of-select-tag-in-php) , [Using $_POST to get select option value from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the text of the selected option using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926906/get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-using-php)

Answer (score 3):

```
<select name="time">
        <option selected="selected" >timings</option>
        <option value="9:00AM - 12:00PM">9:00AM - 12:00PM</option>
        <option value="12:00AM - 15:00PM">12:00AM - 15:00PM</option>
        </select>

<?php
$value = $_POST["time"];  //what method you are using
?>
```

or

```
<select name="time"  >
        <option selected="selected" >timings</option>
        <option value="155">9:00AM - 12:00PM</option>
        <option value="244">12:00AM - 15:00PM</option>
</select>

 <?php
  $value = "";
  switch($_POST['time']){
     case '155':
     $value="9:00AM - 12:00PM";
     break;
     case '244':
     $value = "12:00AM - 15:00PM";
     break;
     default:
     $value = "No data found";  
     break;
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've two options;

1. Use `12:00AM - 15:00PM` inside the `value=""` parameter.

OR

1. Do something like this in PHP file for collecting data and inserting it into db;

   ```
   if ($_POST['time'] == "155")
   {
       $time = '9:00AM - 12:00PM';
   }
   elseif ($_POST['time'] == "244")
   {
       $time = '12:00AM - 15:00PM';
   }
   // do rest of the data insertion into db
   ```

Comment: i want that value and data too i want to post data only not value i want 12:00Am -15:00PM to post not the value like 155 , as value is used for ajax reterival