# get value from dropdownlist and execute a query with php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying that when the user chose a specific value of drop down menu, then to execute a specific query.. I have this drop down menu

```
<select id="cmimetlist" onChange="dropdown()">
  <option value="1"> me pak se 1000</option>
  <option value="2">midis 1000 dhe 2000</option>
  <option value="3">me shume se 2000</option>
 </select>
```

and this function in javascript

```
<script>

function dropdown()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("cmimetlist");
    var vlera = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(vlera);
}
</script>
```

but how to make it that instead of alert do this:

```
if (vlera == 1)
```

then execute this query

```
$run = mysql_query("select * from restorantet, menu where ID_Rest=Rest_ID and Cmimi<1000 ORDER BY Cmimi LIMIT $startrow, 10 ") or Die("ska me te dhena");
```

`if (vlera == 2)` execute another query

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must use ajax, do you use jquery?

Comment: No.is there any opportunity without JQuery and Ajax?

Comment: Of course there is. take a look : http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: nope. If you don't want to reload page, you must use ajax.

Comment: Thanks, I am seeing it

Answer (score 0):

I would stick strictly to php for this as it can do the functionality of the javascript as well

I suggest viewing this similar form post as it will probably help

[Select tags with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695599/get-the-selected-index-value-of-select-tag-in-php)

And querying is simple and you should be able to find how to convert the select tag input into a queryable form of data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interactive with backend (such like php) after page render, you must use `AJAX` technology.

So,

If you use native javascript, search `XmlHttpRequest`

If you use jQuery, search `$.ajax`